# Linke Excel to Access table VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I cannot figure out what is going wrong with my code.  I am trying to link a spreadsheet to a Access table using VBA.  There is no errors in the code but the table is not updating.  I am not looking for the answer but a nudge  in the right direction.

Here is the code:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim xlsht As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlWrkBk As Excel.Workbook
Dim pathXls As String

pathXls = CurrentProject.Path & "\Week7DVDupdate.xlsx"
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWrkBk = GetObject(pathXls)
Set xlsht = xlWrkBk.Worksheets(1)

Dim DVD_Number As String
Dim Movie_Title As String
Dim Year_Released As String
Dim Disk_Type As String
Dim Quantity_in_Stock As Integer
Dim Number_Rented As Integer
Dim Number_of_Times_Rented As Integer

flag = True
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Do While flag = True
    DVD_Number = xlsht.Cells(i, "A")
    Movie_Title = xlsht.Cells(i, "B")
    Year_Released = xlsht.Cells(i, "C")
    Disk_Type = xlsht.Cells(i, "D")
    Quantity_in_Stock = xlsht.Cells(i, "E")
    Number_Rented = xlsht.Cells(i, "F")
    Number_of_Times_Rented = xlsht.Cells(i, "G")

    If Title = "" Then
        flag = False
    End If

    If flag = True Then

        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim strSql As String

        strSql = "SELECT * FROM DVD;"
        rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection
        Dim exist As String
        exist = False

        Do While Not rs.EOF
            If rs!DVD_Number = DVD_Number And rs!Movie_Title = Movie_Title 
    Then
            exist = True
        vEnd If
        rs.MoveNext
   v Loop
    rs.Close

    If exist = False Then
        strSql = "INSERT INTO DVD ( DVD_Number, Movie_Title, Year_Released, Disk_Type, Quantity_in_Stock, Number_Rented, Number_of_Times_Rented ) " & _
            "VALUES('" & DVD_Number & "','" & MovieTitle & "','" & Year_Released & "','" & Disk_Type & "','" & Quantity_in_Stock & "','" & Number_Rented & "','" & Number_of_Times_Rented & "')"
            CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql, lngKt
            ExecuteADO = lngKt
        End If

        Set rs = Nothing
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
MsgBox ("Media Link updated")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer data from Excel to Access you should probably try to do a `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` or something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Week7DVDupdate.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";].SheetName
```

You probably need to change the connection string to something more fitting, see here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/